# HID packets dropping

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, kernel, embedded-linux

I have some packets dropping in my HID driver and whenever it drops the packet i get the "hidg_set_report_complete FAILED".

I tried to debug more to see what is causing the issue and found the req->status is "-108" in the struct usb_request.

Can any body point me what does this status code "-108" means?

This is on Linux-2.6.25 kernel on iMX28 processor

Comment: at least you should describe the hw and os

Comment: @tristan - the operating system was already in the tags.  The HW might matter to solve the ultimate problem being experienced, but **does not matter** to answer the specific question which was asked.

Comment: the hw might also matter to the question that what error code 108 means. it doesn't guarantee an error number has the same value on different archs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not an expert on arm but fwiw this is from kernel source:

```
#define ESHUTDOWN       108     /* Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown */
```